# vue - v-calendar 24h format

Tags: vue.js, vcalendar

I am struggling to set my v-calendar datetime picker to 24h format.

I am reading the documentation but still could not make it work: https://vcalendar.io/

```
<v-date-picker is-expanded id="match-date-time" v-model="date" mode="dateTime" :timezone="timezone" />
```

I tried different settings but did not find the correct props / parameters for it.

Can someone help in this?

Answer (score 3):

Got it, the secret is:

```
:is24hr="format24h"
```

where format24h is a boolean set to true in data definition